# Codeigniter : If first rule validated, no need to check the next rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

How to check if first rule is validated, then no need to check second/third rule, for example:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('children','Do you have children?','required');// e.g : answer no!

$this->form_validation->set_rules('son','How many sons?','required');//second rule
$this->form_validation->set_rules('daughter','How many daughter?','required');//third rule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple just put the first rule and after the form validation  in `IF`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('children','Do you have children?','required'); 
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)    
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('son','How many sons?','required');//second rule
$this->form_validation->set_rules('daughter','How many daughter?','required');//third rule
}
```

If first rule fails then it will check 2nd and 3rd rule else if first rule is validated it will not check the 2nd and 3rd rule

Hope it makes sense

Comment: sorry it does not work, the rule does not return true or false, it contain objects :
print_r($this->form_validation->set_rules('children','Do you have children?','required'))) does not return true or false

Comment: After edit, he needs to run `$this->form_validation->run()` twice to validate & pass thru all rules. I do not like the idea, but it sure makes it work.

Comment: @Kyslik he don't have to run twice see his question if first rule is validated then its understood you don't have to check `$this->form_validation->run() == TRUE` you should use the else case is definitely the validation is true

Answer (score 0):

u can achieve this using callback function in codeignitor or adding your own rule in CI Core Validation Library 
here it is how we use call back functions 
[CI CallBacks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks)

and here it is how we can have own custom validation function
[Custom validation](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/96050/)

Comment: I would not go for `callbacks` in this situation, in this situation it is not validating itself, @Hermann Golden needs something to handle already validated input.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `form_validation` as follows

```
if ($this->form_validation->required($key)){
       //validation did not pass      
}
```

in which `$key` is `$_POST['children']` or `$this->input->post('children');`

TRUE/FALSE table is [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference)